# VSCode Automatically Update SASS Selectors When Renamed in HTML

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, sass

I am trying to find an extension that will **automatically** update my SASS/CSS file when I rename a selector inside my HTML file. Does such an extension exist?

For example, if I rename...

**`div class="main-title"`** to **`div class="primary-title"`**

Then it would automatically update my SASS selector from...

**`.main-title`** to **`.primary-title`**.

Comment: I don't think there is an extension that does that, you will have to do that manually

Comment: @Richie I was afraid that was the case. It would make life much easier if there was! Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an extension I wrote: [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions) v1.1.0

Define the following setting:

```json
  "my-code-actions.actions": {
    "[html]": {
      "Rename CSS class selector": {
        "atCursor": " class=\"([^\"]+)\"",
        "edits": [
          {
            "file": "style.css",
            "action": "replace",
            "ask": [
              {
                "name": "find",
                "placeHolder": "Enter class",
                "title": "Which class to replace:",
                "value": "{{atCursor:$1}}"
              },
              {
                "name": "replace",
                "placeHolder": "Enter class",
                "title": "Rename:",
                "value": "{{ask:find}}"
              }
            ],
            "replaceFind": "\\.{{ask:find}}\\b",
            "replaceGlobal": true,
            "text": ".{{ask:replace}}"
          },
          {
            "action": "replace",
            "replaceFind": "( class=\"[^\"]*?)\\b{{ask:find}}\\b([^\"]*\")",
            "replaceGlobal": true,
            "text": "$1{{ask:replace}}$2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Change the `"file": "style.css"` to your CSS or SASS file name or add an `ask` entry for the file name and use an ask-field to construct the file path.

Comment: Right on, appreciate the response. Will give this a try later today. Thanks!